# Como anexar um arquivo usando Mandrill API?

Tags: javascript, json, email, envio-de-email, mandrill

Iae, galera!
Estou tentando há dois dias, mas ainda não tive sucesso. Sei que estou perto, mas preciso da ajuda de vocês.
Costumo pegar muito jobs com apenas dados fixos (front-end). Então uso a [API do Mandrill](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html) pra enviar, por e-mail, os dados dos formulários.

Na [documentação oficial](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html) diz que ele suporta anexos, desde que o `content` seja posto em base64-encode.

**PROBLEMA:**

Não consigo gerar um anexo no e-mail enviado. Porém, todos os outros dados (Assunto, E-mail de quem enviou, Nome de quem enviou , Corpo do E-mail) chegam ao destinatário normalmente. 
Pra tirar a prova que o `content` do arquivo estava sendo gerado antes do arquivo ser enviado, enviei o mesmo no corpo do e-mail e foi constado que o código do arquivo (base64) está ok.

**CÓDIGO USADO:**

*Apenas pra contextualizar o problema. Não tenho certeza se esse plugin influência no problema, então resolvi citá-lo aqui.*

Como eu uso o [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) para validar o `form`, a requisição `POST` do Mandrill é implemtada dentro da função `submitHandler()`, que nada mais é do que a função que é executada após o sucesso da validação:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#rh-form').validate({
    rules: {
      name: {
        required: true
      },
      ddd: {
        required: true
      },
      phone: {
        required: true
      },
      cv: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      name: {
        required: 'Informe seu nome!'
      },
      ddd: {
        required: 'Informe seu DDD!'
      },
      phone: {
        required: 'Informe seu contato!'
      },
      cv: {
        required: 'Selecione um arquivo!'
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      //AQUI DENTRO FICA O BLOCO DE CÓDIGO DO MANDRILL
      //QUE VOU MOSTRAR A SEGUIR...
    }
  });
});
```

**BLOCO DE CÓDIGO DO MANDRILL:**

```
//PEGO OS DADOS DO FORM
var name = $('input[name="name"]').val(),
          ddd = $('input[name="ddd"]').val(),
          phone = $('input[name="phone"]').val(),
          city = $('input[name="city"]').val(),
          uf = $('select[name="uf"]').val(),
          //CORPO DO E-MAIL
          mailText = '<p><label>Nome: </label>'+ name +'</p><p><label>Telefone: </label> (' + ddd + ') ' + phone + '</p><p><label>Localidade: </label>'+ city +' - '+ uf +'</p>';

      if( $('#fileInput').val() != '') {
        var file = $('#fileInput')[0].files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var fileResult;
        reader.onload = function(event) {
          //FILE RESULT RECEBE O CÓDIGO DO ARQUIVO #fileInput
          fileResult = btoa(event.target.result);
          sendMessage(mailText, name, fileType, fileName, fileResult);
        }
      }

      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
      var fileType = file.type;
      var fileName = file.name;



      var sendMessage = function (mailText, name, fileType, fileName, fileResult) {

        var data = {
          'key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          'message': {
            //ADICIONEI fileResult NO CORPO E TIVE SUCESSO EM VER O CÓDIGO. NADA DE ANEXO
            'html': mailText + '<br><br>'+ fileResult,
            'text': '',
            'subject': 'Testando Anexo',
            'from_email': 'test@example.com',
            'from_name': name,
            'to': [
                {
                  'email': 'meu@email.com',
                  'name': 'Phellipe Lins',
                  'type': 'to'
                }
            ]
          },
          'attachments': [
              {
                  'type': fileType,
                  'name': fileName,
                  'content': fileResult
              }
          ],
          'async': false
        };

        $.post('https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json', data)
          .success(function() {
            window.alert('Contato feito com sucesso!');
            document.getElementById('rh-form').reset();
          })
          .fail(function() {
            window.alert('Ocorreu algum problema.');
          });
      }
```

**PRINT DO E-MAIL DE TESTE**

[image: Segue o e-mail.]

Comment: Uma vez que não usas o ficheiro no lado do cliente podias mandar tudo com um `fromData` para o servidor e tratar a imagem aí. Acho que seria melhor... já experimentaste isso?

Comment: Fui dar uma olhada na documentação e vi que parece diferente o `'attachments'` e `'images'`. Se o seu upload for uma imagem já tentou colocar no `'images'`?

Comment: Trata-se se PDF e DOC, nada de imagens. Não entendi o que dissestes, @Sergio. Teria como explicar de uma outra forma?

Comment: A ideia era enviares essa form para o teu servidor e tratar aí da conversão para base64. Mas se queres fazer com JavaScript podes testar `readAsDataURL` em vez de `readAsBinaryString` + `btoa`. Há [uma resposta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6979300/2256325) que sugere isso também.

Comment: Não tem em nenhum lugar que você fala o tipo do conteúdo?

Comment: Resolveu seu problema?